# Efficient way to modify an object from array of objects via index and insert new objects in the same array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array available in the db with the key heros.

```
Heros: [
{
  name: 'Ironman',
  country: 'USA'
},
{
  name: 'Shaktiman',
  country: 'India'
},
{
  name: 'Black Panther',
  country: 'Wakanda'
}
]
```

and I have a new array which basically have additional heros:

```
additionalHeros = [{ name: 'Wonder woman', country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Kenshiro', country: 'Japan' }]
```

I want to update the name and country of a hero at a specific index say 1 and replace it with new values. After that I have to put all the additional heros in the same query.
After executing update query, expected result would be:

```
At index 2 -> update name: 'Krishh', country: 'India' -> put rest of the heros
```

Updated db value for heros is:

```
Heros: [
{
  name: 'Ironman',
  country: 'USA'
},
{
  name: 'Shaktiman',
  country: 'India'
},
{
  name: 'Krishh',
  country: 'India'
}, 
{ name: 'Wonder woman',
  country: 'USA' 
}, 
{ name: 'Kenshiro',
 country: 'Japan' 
}
]
```

I'm aware of the part to push a value but I can't find any efficient way to update and insert at once

```
 $push: { heros: { $each: additionalHeros } }
```

Comment: 1) regular update query will not allow to 2 operations in same field - it will create conflict 2) you can use an update with aggregation pipeline - but this is not an efficient way to do this operation.

Comment: @turivishal Then what would better, any other good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The regular update query will not allow to do 2 operations in the same field, it will create a conflict error
2. You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2, but i think this approach is not efficient and you want an efficient approach,

   - `$map` to iterate loop of `heros` array
   - `$indexOfArray` to get the index of the current object in `heros` array
   - `$cond` to check if the above return `index` match with our input index then update the latest value otherwise return the same object
   - second `$set` stage to add new `heros` using `$concatArrays` operator

```
additionalHeros = [{ name: 'Wonder woman', country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Kenshiro', country: 'Japan' }]
updateIndex = {
  name: "Krishh",
  country: "India"
}
index = 1
db.collection.updateOne(
  {}, // your query
  [{
    $set: {
      heros: {
        $map: {
          input: "$heros",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                      "$heros",
                      {
                        name: "$$this.name",
                        country: "$$this.country"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  index
                ]
              },
              updateIndex,
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      heros: {
        $concatArrays: ["$heros", additionalHeros]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DoZG3FP87zo)

3. You can do two separate update queries or bulkWrite query

- update specific index property

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {}, // your query
  {
    $set: {
      "heros.1.name": "Krishh",
      "heros.1.country": "India"
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D3Iz9VpGahi)

- push array in `heros`

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  {}, // your query
  {
    $push: {
      heros: {
        $each: [
          {
            name: "Wonder woman",
            country: "USA"
          },
          {
            name: "Kenshiro",
            country: "Japan"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7auoifNeP2V)

Answer (score 1):

this will work
let document be

```
{ 
    "_id" : "heroes", 
    "Heros" : [
        {
            "name" : "Ironman", 
            "country" : "USA"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Shaktiman", 
            "country" : "India"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Black Panther", 
            "country" : "Wakanda"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code would be

```
 let additionalHeros = [{ name: 'Wonder woman', country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Kenshiro', country: 'Japan' }]
    let index = 2;
    let data = { name: 'Krishh', country: 'India' }
    let updateQuery = {};
    updateQuery[`Heros.${index}`] = data;
    let ops = [];
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: "heroes" },
                update: {
                    $set: updateQuery,
                },
                upsert: true
            }
        },
    );
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: "heroes" },
                update: {
                    $push: { Heros: { $each: additionalHeros } }
                },
                upsert: true
            }
        },
    );
    let x = await db1.bulkWrite(ops, { ordered: true, upsert: true })
```

Then Output would be

```
{ 
    "_id" : "heroes", 
    "Heros" : [
        {
            "name" : "Ironman", 
            "country" : "USA"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Shaktiman", 
            "country" : "India"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Krishh", 
            "country" : "India"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Wonder woman", 
            "country" : "USA"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Kenshiro", 
            "country" : "Japan"
        }
    ]
}
```